# Acesso pelo app StackExchange

Tags: suporte

Os acessos ao SOpt através do aplicativo Stack Exchange também contam para a medalha Entusiasta/Fanático?

Comment: Sim, entretanto é necessário executar alguma ação para que o dia seja contabilizado. Fontes: [Entrando na aplicação móvel do Stack Exchange não conta como dia consecutivo?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2216/3117) e [Last seen not updating when using Android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191781/229289)